# EDI X12 FTP protocol, how does it work?

Tags: ftp, edi

We just implemented our EDI module with AS2 support and got a customer that can do FTP only :)

Questions. I know it's "easy" and they give us FTP credentials and IN/OUT path for folders.
How does it work? Here is my understanding, correct me if I'm wrong.

To get new messages, I run my process on schedule every X minutes and:

1. Connect to FTP
2. Open "IN" folder
3. Query for files Get files Delete
4. files Close FTP

To send new messages:

1. Connect to FTP
2. Open "OUT" folder
3. Write my messages
4. Close FTP

Does this sound correct or I need to do something differently?

Comment: This isn't EDI specific, it's customer specific. Your customer will tell you where to receive and send files on their server. Whether you need to delete them after downloading is also dependent on your customer; we've had some that auto-delete after the file is downloaded, for instance. Discuss that with your customer's IT department. This isn't really a programming question.

Comment: Can it be that you need AS3 (FTP-based variant of AS2) ?

Comment: No, it's not AS3, however I do have your component for AS3 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP connections are very common in EDI trading partner relationships.  Instead of delivering data (or listening for data) via HTTP, FTP replaces that in the workflow.  So if your partner is hosting the FTP, you would create your EDI document, pass it off to your communication module which would open the FTP connection, do a CD to the proper directory (if necessary) and do a PUT.  At some point, you will want a process to connect to the FTP server, do a CD (again, if necessary) and do a GET to pull 997s and other inbound (to you) documents.

So your outline is pretty accurate.